# Trying to use a DATE column with pyignite

Tags: python, sql, ignite

When I query my date column I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\datatypes\internal.py", line 390, in __data_class_parse
> return tc_map(type_code)
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\datatypes\internal.py", line 117, in tc_map    return _tc_map[key]
> KeyError: b'\xfe'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "min_repo.py", line 24, in 
> with client.sql('SELECT * FROM DATETEST') as cursor:
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\client.py", line 774, in sql
> return SqlFieldsCursor(self, c_info, query_str, page_size, query_args, schema, statement_type,
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\cursors.py", line 305, in **init**
> self._finalize_init(sql_fields(self.connection, self.cache_info, *args, **kwargs))
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\api\sql.py", line 309, in sql_fields
> return __sql_fields(conn, cache_info, query_str, page_size, query_args, schema, statement_type, distributed_joins,
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\api\sql.py", line 360, in __sql_fields
> return query_perform(
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\queries\query.py", line 49, in query_perform
> return _internal()
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\queries\query.py", line 42, in _internal
> result = query_struct.perform(conn, **kwargs)
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\queries\query.py", line 177, in perform
> raise e
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\queries\query.py", line 167, in perform
> response_ctype = response_struct.parse(stream)
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\queries\response.py", line 110, in parse
> self._parse_success(stream, fields)
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\queries\response.py", line 178, in _parse_success
> field_class = AnyDataObject.parse(stream)
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\datatypes\internal.py", line 378, in parse
> data_class = cls.__data_class_parse(stream)
> File "...\Python\Python38\site-packages\pyignite\datatypes\internal.py", line 392, in __data_class_parse
> raise ParseError('Unknown type code: `{}`'.format(type_code))
> pyignite.exceptions.ParseError: Unknown type code: `b'\xfe'`

My understanding of this is that it tried to decode the type code to match it to its type. It should map to a DateObject with the type code of x\0b. My int and timestamp columns work without issue.

Here is my code:

```py
from pyignite import Client
import datetime

client = Client()

with client.connect("localhost", 10800):
    client.sql("DROP TABLE DATETEST IF EXISTS")
    client.sql('''CREATE TABLE DATETEST (
        ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
        Date DATE, 
        Timestamp TIMESTAMP
    )''')

    insert = '''INSERT INTO DATETEST (
        ID, Date, Timestamp
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'''
    client.sql(insert, query_args=[
        1,
        datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-02"),
        datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-02")
    ])

    with client.sql('SELECT * FROM DATETEST') as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is data types.
The datetime.fromisoformat method returns a datetime.datetime object, which fit Ignit's `Timestamp` type, but not suitable for it's `Date` type, which requires datetime.date:

```py
#You can import the mapping for date with:
from pyignite.datatypes import DateObject
#...
    client.sql(insert, query_args=[
        1,
        datetime.date.fromisoformat("2022-01-02"),
        datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-02")
    ])
```

Nevertheless, the type DATE seems poorly supported by Ignite, and Ignite recommend to use TIMESTAMP instead:

"***Use the TIMESTAMP type instead of DATE whenever possible. The DATE type is serialized/deserialized very inefficiently resulting in performance degradation.***"

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/data-types#date

...so that it could be better to store your date as **TIMESTAMP** in Ignite, and parse it to datetime.date in your python code for computation or display purposes:

```py
    client.sql('''CREATE TABLE DATETEST (
        ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
        Date TIMESTAMP, 
        Timestamp TIMESTAMP
    )''')

    insert = '''INSERT INTO DATETEST (
        ID, Date, Timestamp
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'''
    client.sql(insert, query_args=[
        1,
        datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-02"),
        datetime.datetime.fromisoformat("2022-01-02")
    ])
```